Why can't I create a formula field on a data model object?
Why can't I create a formula field on a data model object?
I am really surprised that Individual standard object doesn't have a Name field unlike Sales Cloud objects to combine basically FirstName and LastName to be used in report.

Formula fields should be defined as data transformation fields on Data Stream but not on Data Model object.

By the way, gack Id
Unable to deploy the data stream, please try again. GackId: 118853105-31132 (389553151)

Happens when you forget to close the parenthesis.
CONCAT(sourceField['first_name'], ' ', sourceField['last_name'])

Also gack error
Unable to add field(s). Please try again later. Gackld: 118853105-31326 (-969553697)   happens when you try to create a new field with the same name.
